# Solaris 10 create username with blank password

Tags: solaris

How to create a script that will create a new user with a blank password in Solaris 10?

Comment: What have you tested so far?

Comment: `passwd -d $user` will delete any password field from a user.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a script to create 1 user? You can just use `useradd -m username`.

If you want to create multiple users, make a file with all the usernames, lets call it usernames. Then this `for` loop will be able to help you out.

```
for i in $( cat usernames ); do
    useradd -m $i
    echo "Adding user $i"
    echo $i:"P@ssW0rd" | chpasswd
done
```

You can also use the `while` loop as @Kusalananda pointed out :

```
while read username ;do
    useradd -m $username
    echo "Adding user $username"
    echo $username:"P@ssW0rd" | chpasswd
done < usernames
```

Comment: What's with the `cat`? Why not `while read ... done <usernames`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I usually use the `for` loop for these kind of things, not too familiar with the `while` loop and with the `< file`.

Comment: Hi Gurus, my boss requirement is to create a user with blank password on Solaris 10. I want know know if you happen to have a script the will automatically create user with blank password or with standard password (P@ssW0rd). The trick is that when you create a new user the password should have no user intervention. Here is the Example. # Script.sh (username) (password)

Comment: When you execute passwd it will require user intervention to keyin the password 2 times. I want to have a script that will eliminate the user intervention so everytime i create a new user with default password it has no user intervention. Thanks

Comment: You should add that to your question then.

Comment: @user3581641, updated the answer, the password for each user will be "P@ssW0rd".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is package for it under Solaris 10 (they added it to v11), but you could use expect.  It's easy to use, as well as compile.  I've done this in the past on Solaris 10 for various efforts.

http://expect.sourceforge.net/

They may even have an example that will meet your needs as a few are password related.